# Magento1: Add Discount_Amount Column in Invoice details

Tags: invoice, discount

I want to add a new column in customer's frontend where they can see also the discount amount.

```
http://example.com/sales/order/invoice/order_id/11111/
```

I would like to add the column in this table.
[image]
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify following two templates:

> app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/sales/order/invoice/items.phtml

```
<?php  $_order = $this->getOrder() ?>
<p class="order-links"><a href="<?php echo $this->getPrintAllInvoicesUrl($_order) ?>" onclick="this.target='_blank'" class="link-print"><?php echo $this->__('Print All Invoices') ?></a></p>
<?php foreach ($_order->getInvoiceCollection() as $_invoice): ?>
    <h2 class="sub-title"><?php echo $this->__('Invoice #') ?><?php echo $_invoice->getIncrementId(); ?> <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $this->getPrintInvoiceUrl($_invoice) ?>" onclick="this.target='_blank'" class="link-print"><?php echo $this->__('Print Invoice') ?></a></h2>
    <h3 class="table-caption"><?php echo $this->__('Items Invoiced') ?></h3>
    <table class="data-table linearize-table" id="my-invoice-table-<?php echo $_invoice->getId(); ?>">
        <col />
        <col width="1" />
        <col width="1" />
        <col width="1" />
        <col width="1" />
        <col width="1" />
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('SKU') ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->__('Discount Amount') ?></th>
            <th class="a-right" data-rwd-label="<?php echo $this->__('Price') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Price') ?></th>
            <th class="a-center" data-rwd-label="<?php echo $this->__('Qty Invoiced') ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Qty Invoiced') ?></span></th>
            <th class="a-right" data-rwd-label="<?php echo $this->__('Subtotal') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <?php echo $this->getInvoiceTotalsHtml($_invoice)?>
        </tfoot>
        <?php $_items = $_invoice->getAllItems(); ?>
        <?php $_count = count($_items) ?>
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
            <?php if ($_item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) continue; ?>
            <tbody>
            <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
            </tbody>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('my-invoice-table-<?php echo $_invoice->getId(); ?>', {'tbody' : ['odd', 'even'], 'tbody tr' : ['first', 'last']})</script>
    <?php echo $this->getInvoiceCommentsHtml($_invoice)?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And

> app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/default.phtml

add following line after SKU column.
    <td data-rwd-label="    <?php echo $this->__('Discount Amount') ?>">    <?php echo $_item->getDiscountAmount();?>    </td>

Now looks like:

```
.........
<td data-rwd-label="<?php echo $this->__('SKU') ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml(Mage::helper('core/string')->splitInjection($this->getSku())) ?></td>
<td data-rwd-label="<?php echo $this->__('Discount Amount') ?>"><?php echo $_item->getDiscountAmount();?></td>
<td class="a-right" data-rwd-label="<?php echo $this->__('Price') ?>">
........
```

Lastly

> app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/sales.xml

```
<sales_order_invoice translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account Order Invoice View</label>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="sales/order_info" as="info" name="sales.order.info">
            <block type="sales/order_info_buttons" as="buttons" name="sales.order.info.buttons" />
        </block>
        <block type="sales/order_invoice" name="sales.order.invoice">
            <block type="sales/order_invoice_items" name="invoice_items" template="sales/order/invoice/items.phtml">
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_item_renderer_default</block><template>sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
                <block type="sales/order_invoice_totals" name="invoice_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
                    <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="5" class="a-right"</value></action>
                    <action method="setValueProperties"><value>class="last a-right"</value></action>
                    <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml" />
                </block>
                <block type="sales/order_comments" name="invoice_comments" template="sales/order/comments.phtml" />
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="sales.order.info">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>view</name><path>*/*/view</path><label>Order Information</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>invoice</name><path></path><label>Invoices</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>shipment</name><path>*/*/shipment</path><label>Shipments</label></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>creditmemo</name><path>*/*/creditmemo</path><label>Refunds</label></action>
    </reference>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
</sales_order_invoice>
```

Especially you change here colspan. Default 4, now you need to change that 5.

Clear cache.

So overwrite these two templates and added a new column. For base template file you can find under **base/default** directory instead of **rwd/default**.

**Note:** *Don't modify core file.*

Comment: it's magento 1, not magento 2

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: yea, i know the files, but i want the code to update the files. so please write the code modifications. thank you

Comment: Check updated answer